# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape', and path is CORRECT

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to take all the photos in a certain folder, ending with .jpeg and make it to a video using opencv.

problem is for some reason After I try to get the img.shape it returns me an error, I read a lot while searching for an answer and pretty all of them said the same, that the path is incorrect, so I've tested it with `os.path.isfile()` function and it returns true so I am not sure

```
def make_move(path):
    image_folder = path
    video_name = 'video.avi'
    images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".jpeg")]
    frame = cv2.imread(image_folder + images[0], cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    print(os.path.isfile(image_folder + images[0]))# True
    print(frame) # prints None
    height, width, layers = frame.shape # Error here


    video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, 0, 1, (width,height))

    for image in images:
         video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image)))

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    video.release()
```

As I mentioned I get NoneType error, even tho the path is correct.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: Is the image_folder path a relative path ? It can explain why it doesn't work, use an absolute path for your image folder. (Also think about using os.path.join instead of using string concat).

Comment: @abcdaire can you give me an example using os.path.join, i saw it while searching and could not fully understand it

Comment: @yarinCohen os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]) , you can have a look at the documentation to understand it. Concerning your bug I think the main issue is that your image_folder is a relative path , basically you pass a relative path to your function. So either you pass an absolute path , or you can reconstruct the absolute path and then pass it to cv2.imread

Comment: for some reason when i opened python sheel in the images folders, it worked when  i putted in the path '0.png'

Answer (score 0):

With concat, you might miss a slash, or backslash if you are on windows. For example:

```
image_folder = '/path/to/folder'
image_file = '1.jpg'

print(image_folder + image_file) # /path/to/folder1.jpg

print(os.path.join(image_folder, image_file) # /path/to/folder/1.jpg
```

And `os.path.join` guarantee stability across system.